# extracting values in a specific column and processing other columns values in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

The following is a simplified blob of my dataframe. I want to process

[first.csv](https://gist.github.com/ecenm/97248a1d1f6f301d662c6f238b6168df#file-first-csv)

```
No.,Time,Source,Destination,Protocol,Length,Info,src_dst_pair
325778,112.305107,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,64,Who has 253.244.230.77?  Tell 253.244.230.67,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
801130,261.868118,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,64,Who has 253.244.230.156?  Tell 253.244.230.67,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
700094,222.055094,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,60,Who has 253.244.230.77?  Tell 253.244.230.156,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
766543,247.796156,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,TCP,66,32222 > http [SYN] Seq=0,"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
767405,248.073313,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,TCP,64,32222 > http [ACK] Seq=1,"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
767466,248.083268,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,HTTP,380,Continuation [Packet capture],"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
891394,294.989813,105.144.38.121,41.177.26.15,TCP,66,48852 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1,"('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15')"
892285,295.320654,105.144.38.121,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,48852 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0,"('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15')"
892287,295.321003,105.144.38.121,41.177.26.15,HTTP,350,Continuation or non-HTTP traffic[Packet size limited during capture],"('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15')"
893306,295.652079,105.144.38.121,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,48852 > http [ACK] Seq=293 Ack=609 Win=64928 Len=0,"('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15')"
893307,295.652233,105.144.38.121,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,"48852 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=293 Ack=609 Win=64928 Len=0","('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15')"
885501,294.070377,105.144.38.139,41.177.26.15,TCP,66,48810 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1,"('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15')"
887786,294.402349,105.144.38.139,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,48810 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0,"('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15')"
887788,294.402642,105.144.38.139,41.177.26.15,HTTP,371,Continuation or non-HTTP traffic[Packet size limited during capture],"('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15')"
890133,294.732297,105.144.38.139,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,"48810 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=314 Ack=629 Win=64907 Len=0","('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15')"
890154,294.733413,105.144.38.139,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,48810 > http [ACK] Seq=315 Ack=630 Win=64907 Len=0,"('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15')"
902758,297.792645,105.144.38.164,41.177.26.15,TCP,66,49005 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1,"('105.144.38.164', '41.177.26.15')"
903926,298.123157,105.144.38.164,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,49005 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0,"('105.144.38.164', '41.177.26.15')"
903932,298.123369,105.144.38.164,41.177.26.15,HTTP,350,Continuation or non-HTTP traffic[Packet size limited during capture],"('105.144.38.164', '41.177.26.15')"
905269,298.455368,105.144.38.164,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,49005 > http [ACK] Seq=293 Ack=609 Win=64928 Len=0,"('105.144.38.164', '41.177.26.15')"
905273,298.455557,105.144.38.164,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,"49005 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=293 Ack=609 Win=64928 Len=0","('105.144.38.164', '41.177.26.15')"
906162,298.714281,105.144.38.204,41.177.26.15,TCP,66,49050 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1,"('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15')"
907292,299.025951,105.144.38.204,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,49050 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0,"('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15')"
907294,299.026985,105.144.38.204,41.177.26.15,HTTP,354,Continuation or non-HTTP traffic[Packet size limited during capture],"('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15')"
907811,299.362918,105.144.38.204,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,49050 > http [ACK] Seq=297 Ack=613 Win=64924 Len=0,"('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15')"
907812,299.362951,105.144.38.204,41.177.26.15,TCP,64,"49050 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=297 Ack=613 Win=64924 Len=0","('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15')"
```

How can I do the following in pandas? For each unique `df.src_dst_pair` (last element in each row):

1. Check if `df.Info` has `[SYN]`. If not, skip the row.
2. If `df.Info` has `[SYN]`, store the `df.Time` (indicates start time)
3. Start accumulating the `df.Length` from `[SYN]` till we find `[FIN, ACK]`
4. Once we find the `[FIN, ACK]` in `df.info`, store the `df.Time` (indicates stop time). If no `[FIN, ACK]` is found in `df.Info` for a `df.src_dst_pair`, then skip the `df.src_dst_pair`.
5. Finally, summarize the result.

```
df.src_dst_pair: flow number, (accumulated) df.Length, df.Time(stop)-df.Time(start)
```

**Expected output for first.csv**

```
('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15') : flow 1, 1118, 0.66242
('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15') : flow 1, 565,  0.028527
('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15') : flow 2, 608,  0.662912
('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15') : flow 1, 612,  0.64867
```

**My approach:**

```
import pandas
import numpy


data = pandas.read_csv('first.csv')
print data

uniq_src_dst_pair = numpy.unique(data.src_dst_pair.ravel())
print uniq_src_dst_pair
print len(uniq_src_dst_pair)

# for now only able to sort data based on src_dst_pair, need flow info. 
result = data.groupby('src_dst_pair').Length.sum()
print result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


def extract_flows(g):
    # Find the location of SYN packets
    is_syn = g['Info'].fillna('').str.contains('\[SYN\]')
    syn = g[is_syn].index.values

    # Find the location of the FIN-ACK packets
    is_finack = g['Info'].fillna('').str.contains('\[FIN, ACK\]')
    finack = g[is_finack].index.values

    # Loop over SYN packets
    runs = []
    for num, start in enumerate(syn, start=1):
        try:
            # Find the first FIN-ACK packet after each SYN packet
            #     If none, raises IndexError
            stop = finack[finack > start][0]
            runs.append([# The flow number counter
                         num,
                         # The time difference between the packets
                         g.loc[stop, 'Time'] - g.loc[start, 'Time'],
                         # The accumulated length
                         g.loc[start:stop, 'Length'].sum()])
        except IndexError:
            break

    # The output must be a DataFrame
    output = (pd.DataFrame(runs, columns=['Flow number', 'Time', 'Length'])
                .set_index('Flow number'))
    return output


df = pd.read_csv('first.csv', usecols = ['src_dst_pair', 'Info', 'Time', 'Length'])

result = df.groupby('src_dst_pair').apply(extract_flows)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
                                                    Time  Length
src_dst_pair                       Flow number                  
('105.144.38.121', '41.177.26.15') 1            0.662420   608.0
('105.144.38.139', '41.177.26.15') 1            0.661920   565.0
                                   2            0.662912   608.0
('105.144.38.204', '41.177.26.15') 1            0.648670   612.0
```

*N.B.*: the sample data in the OP does not coincide with that in the linked `first.csv`. Some of the numbers in the above output coincide with the OP's desired output for processing of `first.csv` — yet others differ, and I think mine are the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks, i shall check and let you know.

Comment: Hi Alberto, I tried you code. It worked for smaller samples. But when I tried on the following dataset (https://github.com/ecenm/data/blob/master/sorted.csv.zip). It gives a `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` in the `File "first.py", line 37, in <module>
    result = df.groupby('src_dst_pair').apply(extract_flows)`

Comment: The file you link to contains `NaN`s in the `Info` column (your sample does not), which forced `is_syn` and `is_finack` into a `float` dtype instead of `bool`. Filling those `NaN`s with empty strings fixes it --- see edit.